# What java policy do you need to allow Class.getResource("name")

Tags: java, security-policy

I am attempting to invoke the following:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)
```

However it fails (returns null) when I turn on the following java security policy. I can't find what I have to change to allow it to works?

```
grant {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/tmp", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/tmp/directory.db", "read, write";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "data.folder", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "loadLibrary.*";
};
```

Comment: It's less likely to be security issue and more likely that you are not referencing a valid resource

Comment: This is an existing application, that works fine. The problem only occurs when I turn on the security policy.

Comment: Under some OS's `/` is a protected domain...